# Search user in selection by uid and change specific field in firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my firebase, I have a selection `users`, which contains all the user and their information.

```
root / users / document / selection with fields uid, emailVerified ...
```

The id of the document is generated automatically by firebase. Now I want to find a specific user by his uid and change the value of the field `emailVerified` to `true`, if it is `false`.

```
updateVerificationStatusEmail() {
  let uid = this.uid;
  this.afStore.collection(`users/${uid}`).update({emailVerified:true}); 
}
```

I get an error:

```
Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but users/FbItk9NecGMkTeDKqq90rZpVYnS2 has 2
```

I think the problem is that I can't iterate through the dynamically generated documents. Thank you for your hints!

Answer (score 0):

Since `uid` is a document, then use the following:

```
this.afStore.collection("users").doc(`${uid}`).update({emailVerified:true});
```

Comment: It's not working. I get an error ' FirebaseError: [code=not-found]: No document to update: .../databases/(default)/documents/users/FbItk9NecGMkTeDKqq90rZpVYnS2'

Comment: isnt that what you want? I thought the `uid` is the document id

Comment: unfortunately not...the document id is an automatically generated id by firebase

Comment: uid is a field of every document